# Electric wheelchairs hire in Cologne

Tags: germany, rental, accessibility, cologne

I plan to visit Germany, Cologne particularly, from Moscow this fall. Unfortunately, I'm disabled, so I need to temporary hire an electric wheelchair. If anybody knows organizations, please help to find some. It would be nice to hire wheelchair and deliver it the hotel I will ride from the airport. Hire period is for one week, probably.

Comment: Are you after one for the whole time you're Germany, or would you re-hire in each city? Where are you flying into - Cologne, first?

Comment: Yes, I think about Cologne. This is one city only trip, I plan to be there for a week. I'll arrive in Cologne via flight from Moscow. So, I will need a taxi transfer with accessibility, and need an electric (only this type) wheelchair to riding. I found this company: http://www.disabledaccessholidays.com , but they do addicts in Berlin or Munich by default. So, if I won't find something else, I'll ask them to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the http://disabledaccessholidays.com company I specified above, to hire wheelchair and car transfer. I communicated with them. They can help not only in Berlin and München, but in Köln, too. Hope this question can be useful for someone who will find it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [bike rental](http://www.radstationkoeln.de/radstation-hbf/fahrrad-verleih.html) at the [Hauptbahnhof](http://www.radstationkoeln.de/lageplan.html) which offers rental of wheelchairs (although they don't specify, so I guess it's the non-electric ones), handbikes and electric scooters.

There are some details including pictures and prices for the electric scooters on the [website of the city of Cologne](http://www.stadt-koeln.de/leben-in-koeln/soziales/behinderung/ausleihe-von-elektromobilen). The price is 10 € for 3 hours or 20 € per day plus a deposit of 100 €. As they state on the website, this offer is also specifically aimed at disabled tourists and not only locals.

Comment: I don't think an electric scooter would be useful for Evgeniy

Comment: Yes, I figured it might not fit everyone's need. But since they are especially marketed at people with reduced mobility I think it's good to mention the offer for reference to other people with similar questions.

Comment: Yes, it is right. I need an electric type of wheelchair because of my weak hands. Thanks, @drat, I'll write them in any way - maybe they do has EWC or will advise something else.

Answer (score 4):

I found Köln-Turismus company and wrote them. They gave me +49 0221 949755 - 0 and the E-mail Adress is info@stortz-koeln.de I'll write them - but did anybody hear about them?

Manager from disabledaccessholidays.com said that, fortunately, they can provide an electric wheelchair in Köln, too. His colleague trying to organize a transfer. If it will be possible (I hope it will) - it will be great.

Comment: If I look them up, it seems like an regular health care center, not oriented towards tourists whatsoever. I have no relevant experience to share with you on this.

Comment: Yes, you're right probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can rent wheelchairs, scooters and walkers in many cities in Germany on: https://meinhilfsmittel.de/en

(Note: I am one of the developers of the site, if you have any question feel free to ask :)